# How do I create an IAM Principal for an account using AWS CDK for Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I want to create a policy that looks like this (which will permit cross account access to a SNS topic):

```
{
  "Statement":[{
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Principal":{
      "AWS":"111122223333"
    },
    "Action":"sns:Subscribe",
    "Resource":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:MyTopic"
  }]
}
```

How do I create this using the Java CDK?  I think I should be using `AccountPrincipal` but I can't find a class that seems relevant that has a public constructor.

```
myTopic.addToResourcePolicy(
    PolicyStatement.Builder
        .create()
        .actions(List.of("sns:Subscribe"))
        .effect(Effect.ALLOW)
        .resources(List.of("arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:MyTopic"))
        .principals(List.of(  ...how do I create a principal here?... ))
        .build()
);
```

Comment: `AccountPrincipal` 's constructor is protected, so you can instead use `AccountRootPrincipal`. `List.of(new AccountRootPrincipal())` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`AccountRootPrincipal`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/java/software/amazon/awscdk/services/iam/AccountRootPrincipal.html) (which implements `IPrincipal`) like below:

```
List.of(new AccountRootPrincipal())
```